# How do I stop the screen flickering when moving my character by pressing the arrow keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-canvas

Can anybody help me with my problem please? I've managed to clear the canvas before redrawing my game character, but was wondering how to stop the screen from flickering as the character moves in JavaScript. Thank you for your help. Help much appreciated. Here's my code.

```
var avatarX = 0;
var avatarY = 267;
var avatarImage;
var counter = 1;
var XWIDTH = 0;
var WIDTH = 400;
var dx = 5;
var tt;

window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown);

function setUpGame() { //This is the function that is called from the html document.
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas"); //Declare a new variable & assigns it the id of the CANVAS from the html document.
avatarImage = new Image(); //Declaring a new variable. This is so that we can store the image at a later date.

avatarImage.src = "img/avatar.png"; //Ditto from above.


gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatarImage, Math.random() * 100, avatarY);
var tt = setInterval(function(){counTer()},1000);
setInterval(handleTick, 25);

}

function KeyDown(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
  case 39: /*Arrow to the right*/
      if(avatarX + dx <WIDTH && avatarX + dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX += dx;
         gameCanvas.width = gameCanvas.width;
      }
    break;
   case 37: /*Arrow to the left*/
      if(avatarX - dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX -= dx;
         gameCanvas.width = gameCanvas.width;
      }
    break;
  }
}

function counTer() {
  if(counter == 60) {
    clearInterval(tt);
  } else {
    counter++;
    gameCanvas.width = 400;
    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").font = "18px Iceland";
    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").textBaseline = "top";
    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").fillText("Seconds: " + counter, 5, 5);
  }
}

function handleTick() {

    gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatarImage, avatarX, avatarY);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations:**

- Create the context once at the top of your code instead of every time you use it.
- Set the font and textBaseline once at the top of your code instead of every time you use it.
- Clear the canvas only when needed (only in handleTick).
- Draw the clock-timer at the same time you draw the avatar (saves 1 canvas clearing).
- Attach an onload function to avatarImage so you know the image is ready to drawImage

Here's modified code -- it's untested so you'll need to review it ;)

*Good luck with your project!*

```
var avatarX = 0;
var avatarY = 267;
var avatarImage;
var counter = 1;
var XWIDTH = 0;
var WIDTH = 400;
var dx = 5;
var tt;
var gameCanvas;
var context;


window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown);

function setUpGame() { //This is the function that is called from the html document.

    gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas"); //Declare a new variable & assigns it the id of the CANVAS from the html document.
    context=gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = "18px Iceland";
    context.textBaseline = "top";

    avatarImage = new Image(); //Declaring a new variable. This is so that we can store the image at a later date.
    avatarImage.onload=function(){

        // avatarImage is now fully loaded and ready to drawImage
        context.drawImage(avatarImage, Math.random() * 100, avatarY);

        // start the timer
        tt = setInterval(function(){counTer()},1000);
        setInterval(handleTick, 25);

    }
    avatarImage.src = "img/avatar.png"; //Ditto from above.

}

function KeyDown(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
  case 39: /*Arrow to the right*/
      if(avatarX + dx <WIDTH && avatarX + dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX += dx;
      }
    break;
   case 37: /*Arrow to the left*/
      if(avatarX - dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX -= dx;
      }
    break;
  }
}

function counTer() {
  if(counter == 60) {
    clearInterval(tt);
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
}

function handleTick() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(avatarImage, avatarX, avatarY);
    context.fillText("Seconds: " + counter, 5, 5);
}
```